# How to run android qpython script from cmd (DroidEdit, terminal)?

Tags: android, cmd, qpython

I would like to run qpython scripts from the editor "DroidEdit" as the external commands. And also from the command line in terminal "Terminal Emulator for Android."

I tried this method: http://wiki.qpython.org/en/diveinto/#how-to-execute-qpythons-python-in-other-terminals

but it is not working. I first tried it in the terminal. The command '$python' does nothing because the variable $python is empty. Command 'python' is not found.

My question is, how do I run 'qpython scripts' from DroidEdit as external command and from terminal on Android?

Comment: Same problem... I would like to use tasker but no way :(

Answer (score 0):

First, You could "share to" qpython from 3rd apps.

Second,You need to root the android device first, then soure the env vars  (Just like the qpython wiki link you mentioned) and execute the /data/data/org.qpython.qpy/bin/python or /data/data/org.qpython.qpy/bin/python-android5